# Nginx serving files from non-domain url?

Tags: nginx

Is it possible for me to have an nginx server's domain to contain slashes? For example, for the server's root url location to be `https://example.com/apps/app1`?

I have a server whose files need to be served from `/opt/production/app1/public`. My current `nginx.conf` configuration, which doesn't work, contains:

```
location /apps/app1 {
    root /opt/production/app1/public;
}
```

But obviously, this doesn't work because my files aren't at `/opt/production/app1/public/apps/app1`. I would like for nginx to consider https://example.com/app/apps1 to be my domain, so that my nginx.conf can access content as so:

```
location / {
    root /opt/production/app1/public;
}
```

Is this at all possible? If not (which I suspect is the case), is there a way to work around this w/o changing the url schema?

Comment: If I were you, rather than fiddling with nginx I'd suggest setting a symlink where nginx expects your files to be, pointed at where you want the files to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can try an [`alias`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) directive for `/apps/app1/` location:

```
location /apps/app1/ {
    alias /opt/production/app1/public/;
}
```